# Illegal operand of type void when defining UnaryPredicate

Tags: c++, std

I'm trying to use std::partition with a custom UnaryPredicate.

```
void Rank(vector< pair<double, string> >& pairs) const
{
    partition(pairs.begin(), pairs.end(), [](const pair<double, string>& a) { isnan(a.first); });
}
```

When doing this I get the following errors from Visual Studio 2015:

- Error    C2297   '&&': illegal, right operand has type
  'void'   Imaging c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
  14.0\vc\include\algorithm    1839
- Error    C2171   '!': illegal on operands of type 'void' Imaging c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
  14.0\vc\include\algorithm    1844
- Error    C2297   '&&': illegal, right operand has type 'void'    Imaging c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
  visual studio 14.0\vc\include\algorithm  1844

The following however has not issue:

```
bool pairIsNan(const pair<double, string>& a)
{
    return isnan(a.first);
}
partition(pairs.begin(), pairs.end(), pairIsNan);
```

Can anyone clarify what is wrong with the first set of code and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your lambda doesn't return anything, it's corresponding function is really something like:

```
void pairIsNan(const pair<double, string>& a)
{
    // Discard the result of the isnan function
    (void) isnan(a.first);
}
```

To make it work you need to return the result of the `isnan` function call in the lambda:

```
partition(pairs.begin(), pairs.end(), [](const pair<double, string>& a)
{
    // Return the result
    return isnan(a.first);
});
```

Comment: That was a silly mistake.  Thanks for pointing out something that should have been obvious.